# Cannot run test block in IntelliJ with Jest if api included

Tags: node.js, testing, intellij-idea, jestjs, tls1.2

This is an issue I recently run into when I did a block run for the test file. This is a react project with redux, there are some APIs I directly hit into. It works before, but now the API cannot be reached and fail the tests. I set environment variables to export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0, but got no luck. I can run the file by calling the command we use cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 jest , but the IntelliJ block run fails anyway. Of course, if there is no API, it works well. I'm wondering what's the reason behind it and how to fix this. This bothers me a lot, 'cause we have tons of tests, block run is very helpful for debugging.

Comment: not enough info to see what can be wrong; sample project the issue can be repeated with would be helpful

Comment: sorry, I cannot put more code on this. It's from my company code source. I fixed this issue by pointing the Node version to my local path. And it works now